# XML import into SQL Server using OPENROWSET and OPENXML

Tags: sql-server, xml, openxml, openrowset

Have never done this before, seem to be having issues with namespaces? Any help would be appreciated. If I remove the `xmlns` attributes from my XML file it works fine...

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ETS xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3 ETS_v3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3">
<WellTours>
<WellTour>
<LicenseNo>001</LicenseNo>
<WellName>75-998</WellName>
</WellTour>
<WellTour>
<LicenseNo>007</LicenseNo>
<WellName>14-172</WellName>
</WellTour>
</WellTours>
</ETS>
```

Here is my SQL:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SELECT @xml=I
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\CCTESTFILE.XML', SINGLE_BLOB) as ImportFile(I)

SELECT @xml

DECLARE @hdoc int

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xml

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, '/ETS/WellTours/WellTour',2)
WITH (
        WellName varchar(100),
        LicenseNo varchar(100));

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Much simpler to just use the built-in **XQuery** functionality instead of the old, bulky and memory-leaking `OPENXML` approach:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3')
SELECT
    LicenseNo = XC.value('(LicenseNo)[1]', 'varchar(10)'),
    WellName = XC.value('(WellName)[1]', 'varchar(25)')
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/ETS/WellTours/WellTour') AS XT(XC)
```

Gives me an output of:

[image]

Comment: @C-COOP: if you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason you have to use `openxml` then you need to add namespace declaration to `sp_xml_preparedocument` call. Something like this.

```
declare @xml varchar(max)= --no need to declare as xml
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ETS xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3 ETS_v3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3">
<WellTours>
<WellTour>
<LicenseNo>001</LicenseNo>
<WellName>75-998</WellName>
</WellTour>
<WellTour>
<LicenseNo>007</LicenseNo>
<WellName>14-172</WellName>
</WellTour>
</WellTours>
</ETS>'

DECLARE @hdoc int

--Note x: before ETS and :x after xmlns
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @xml, '<x:ETS xmlns:x="http://www.caodc.ca/ETS/v3" />'

--Note x: before elements
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML (@hdoc, 'x:ETS/x:WellTours/x:WellTour',2)
WITH (
        WellName varchar(100) 'x:WellName',
        LicenseNo varchar(100) 'x:LicenseNo');

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc
```